# Discord.JS UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.edit is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Ok, so my code simply uses a request to check a website. if the body includes the right text, it should edit the embed, to the correct status (Basically its a status bot.) For some reason i get an error saying message.edit is not a function. Here is my code, any help is GREATLY appreciated!

This part is in my index.js file (client.on ready)

```
    client.on("ready", async (message) => {
    console.log("Ready!")
    gettingLandingStatus()
 // LANDING PAGE STATUS STARTS HERE!
    async function gettingLandingStatus() {
        const channelID = "814563128104058942";
        const landingOnline = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Crackingcord Landing Page Status")
        .addField("Crackingcord Landing Page Live Status:", ":green_circle: | Landing Page Is Fully Operational!")
        .setFooter("Last Updated : ")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('AQUA')
    const landingOffline = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Crackingcord Landing Page Status")
        .addField("Crackingcord Landing Page Live Status:", ":green_circle: | Landing Page Is Fully Operational!")
        .setFooter("Last Updated : ")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('DARK_RED')

    await request("https://crackingcord.xyz", {method: 'POST'}, function (err, res, body){
    if(res.body.includes("Landing Page | Crackingcord")) {
        client.channels.cache.get('814563128104058942').messages.fetch({ around: '827990450581274704', limit: 1 }).then(async m => {
            m.edit(landingOnline)
        })
    } else if (res.body.includes("Maintenance | Crackingcord")){
        client.channels.cache.get('814563128104058942').messages.fetch({ around: '827990450581274704', limit: 1 }).then(async m => {
            m.edit(landingOffline)
        })
    }})}setInterval(gettingLandingStatus, 30000)
    //LANDING PAGE STATUS ENDS HERE!


})
```

This part is my setup file (Which sends the original messages. it is called setup.js inside my /commands/main/ folder)

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
var request = require('request');
module.exports = {
    name: "setup",
    category: "main",
    description: "Start The Status",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
    
        const landingStatus = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Crackingcord Landing Page Status")
        .addField("Crackingcord Landing Page Live Status:", "Null")
        .setFooter("Last Updated : ")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('AQUA')
        await message.channel.send(landingStatus)

        const movieStatus = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Crackingcord Movies Status")
        .addField("Crackingcord Movies Live Status:", "Null")
        .setFooter("Last Updated : ")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('BLUE')
        await message.channel.send(movieStatus)

        const crackStatus = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Crackingcord Cracks Status")
        .addField("Crackingcord Cracks Live Status:", "Null")
        .setFooter("Last Updated : ")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('PURPLE')
        await message.channel.send(crackStatus)

}}
```

Sorry if it is a dumb or easy fix. I am not used to using requests or editing embed messages. I mostly focus on moderation or general use functions.

Comment: It's not a good idea to keep reusing `message` since it's already defined to your global message object. When handling the promise, i recommend using `msg` or `m` to reference the different message.

Comment: but this wont fix the issue.

Comment: Which is why I commented instead of posting as an answer.